# OnTriggerEnter in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tell me please. I have a character. The character has a child element - sphere collider. This sphere is a trigger. There is a script that is located on the Terrain. How can I call the OnTriggerEnter function in this script which is located on the character sphere?

Terrain script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Human;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        var humanTrigger = Human.Find("Trigger");
        humanTrigger OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
            print(other);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OnTriggerEnter is called only  on trigger enter, you don't call it manually

Comment: Technically you can make `OnTirggerEnter` public and call it like `humanTrigger.OnTriggerEnter(somecollider)`, but doing so is kind of pointless. What are you even trying to do?